# Getting: conflicts with same file imported from GOPATH with google app engine, but not purely locally

Tags: google-app-engine

I am still trying to deploy to google app engine both the local test environment and on app engine itself, and I keep getting this error:

```
2017/10/03 17:50:40 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: app file DbConfig.go conflicts with same file imported from GOPATH
```

I have used grep to see if I explicitly import `DbConfig` but I, this is the result of grep:

```
$ grep -r 'DbConfig' .
./config.go:func GetDatabaseConfiguration() model.DbConfig {
./config.go:    return model.DbConfig{connectionName, user, password, dbType, dbName}
Binary file ./share-services matches
./queries/db-config.go: dbConfig model.DbConfig
./queries/db-config.go:func Config(newDbConfig model.DbConfig) {
./queries/db-config.go: dbConfig = newDbConfig
./model/DbConfig.go:type DbConfig struct {
./model/DbConfig.go:func (d DbConfig) ConnectionString() string {
```

So from what I can tell I should not get an error and since other structs from my model package works just fine this is very strange to me. Firstly because Google App Engine accepts the deploy and first fails later, secondly because the dev server fails immediately, and lastly because if I run outside the app engine, I don't get this error.

Can someone give me a pointer to how to fix this please. I have search for a fix, but most state to use absolute include paths for packages which I already am.

EDIT: 
I forgot to include the build command used, maybe that will help

```
go-app-builder -app_base /home/tools/go/src/bitbucket.com/chocolate-cloud-dev/share-services -arch 6 -dynamic -goroot /home/tools/sdks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.6 -gopath /home/tools/go -nobuild_files ^^$ -incremental_rebuild -unsafe -print_extras_hash links/generator.go model/user.go model/service.go model/SharedWith.go handlers.go config.go model/connection.go jsonHelpers/decoders.go queries/share-with-queries.go authentication/autenticate.go queries/share-queries.go model/share.go download/download.go model/Download.go model/File.go queries/file-queries.go jsonHelpers/encoders.go queries/db-config.go model/DbConfig.go model/NewestFile.go share-services.go jsonHelpers/CreateShare.go queries/download-queries.go
```

And this is my project structure:

```
.
├── app.yaml
├── authentication
│   └── autenticate.go
├── build-and-run
├── config.go
├── deply_v1.sh
├── download
│   └── download.go
├── go-notes.md
├── handlers.go
├── jsonHelpers
│   ├── CreateShare.go
│   ├── decoders.go
│   └── encoders.go
├── LICENSE
├── links
│   └── generator.go
├── model
│   ├── connection.go
│   ├── DbConfig.go
│   ├── Download.go
│   ├── File.go
│   ├── NewestFile.go
│   ├── service.go
│   ├── SharedWith.go
│   ├── share.go
│   └── user.go
├── models
├── queries
│   ├── db-config.go
│   ├── download-queries.go
│   ├── file-queries.go
│   ├── queries.sql
│   ├── share-queries.go
│   └── share-with-queries.go
├── README.md
├── run-locally-mac.sh
├── run-localy.sh
├── scripts
│   └── Script.sql
└──  share-services.go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is to either use relative paths instead of absolute, which still does not totaly work Or make a 100% flat folder structure.